# suitescript 2.0:How to set excel style when export po to a csv file

Tags: netsuite

There is a funtion that I need to export a Purchase Order to csv file.I have got the data and put it into a cvs file.Now I want adjust excel style,like merged cells,center my text,through script or set template.But I do not know how to do it. Is there any demo or suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a csv file, you can't put special formatting on it when creating it. Its just plain text file with each column separated by comma.